# How to evaluate TWave instance of Sympy Optics module?

Tags: python, sympy

I have problem evaluating the TWave instance of Sympy optics module.

At first, I tried with `lambdify()` using this code:

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.physics.optics import TWave
import numpy as np

A, f, phi = symbols('A f phi')
wave = TWave(A, f, phi)

# the evaluation
xpoint = tpoint = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
fb = lambdify([A, f, phi, x, t, n], wave.rewrite('cos'))
fb(1, 1000, 0.5*np.pi, xpoint, tpoint, 1)
```

However, I got this error: `AttributeError: 'Float' object has no attribute 'cos'` instead.

---

Then I try a simple `evalf()` for just one point, just to make sure.

```
# evaluation with evalf()
data = {
    'A0': 1,
    'f' : 100,
    'phi' : np.pi/2,
}

ff = wave.subs(data).rewrite('cos')
ff
# result: TWave instance, rewritten in cosine term, with variable substituted
```

Now, what came afterward made me wonder:
At a glance, I saw that there are 3 variables that need to be substituted, namely `x, t, n`. However, when I tried this:

```
ff.subs({'x':1, 't':10, 'n':1})
```

I got `ValueError: summation of quantities of incompatible dimensions` error instead. I tried to remove the `n` from the subs dictionary:

```
ff.subs({'x':1, 't':10})
```

it worked, but with `n` still a symbolic instance. Thus, I cannot get any numeric value out of `ff.subs({'x':1, 't':10}).evalf()`

Any idea? I just want to be able to evaluate the transverse wave value at any given point(s).

Thanks,

PS: might not relevant, but I'm using Sympy 1.2 on Anaconda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue has to do with `TWave` adding units to the expression without telling you.

`wave.rewrite('cos')` gives `A*cos(-2*pi*f*t + phi + pi*second*f*n*x/(149896229*meter))`. If you eliminate the `meter` and `second` symbols, your code works.

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.physics.optics import TWave
from sympy.physics.units import meter, second
import numpy as np

A, f, phi = symbols('A f phi')
wave = TWave(A, f, phi)

# the evaluation
xpoint = tpoint = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
fb = sympy.lambdify(
    [A, f, phi, x, t, n], 
    wave.rewrite(
        'cos'
    ).subs(
        [(meter, 1), (second, 1)]
    ), 
    modules='numpy'
)
fb(1, 1000, 0.5*np.pi, xpoint, tpoint, 1)
```

Comment: Did notice it but oblivious that one need to import this line `from sympy.physics.units import meter, second` to substitue both units.
Thanks for the help, it works!